# Is it bad to use double slashes in the URL path?

Tags: apache, url, browser, url-rewriting

My feed reader uses URLs like `http://example.com/feed/feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml`. This URL displays content from `http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml`.

I've recently added a pagination feature by appending `/page/123` to the end of URLs. For example, page 2 of the BBC feed would be `http://example.com/feed/feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml/page/2`.

However, some feed URLs end in slashes, such as `http://news.yahoo.com/news/`. Page 2 of this feed would be `http://example.com/feed/news.yahoo.com/news//page/2`. Is this double slash bad? Will any browser ignore the double slash and request `http://example.com/feed/news.yahoo.com/news/page/2` instead? `http://example.com/feed/news.yahoo.com/news/page/2` returns 404 not found.

P.S. I'm using Apache's rewrite module to send all requests to a PHP script that processes the rewriting.

Comment: Yes. It will work. For example, on Firefox, url can looks like: 
"google.com//page//2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (especially in the [Normalization and Comparison](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6) section) suggesting that a slash in the URI path could be removed, no matter in which context.

Generally, every single character is meaningful. So your two URIs (with and without the second slash) are *different URIs*.

#### Example

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki// redirects to
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29,

while

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ redirects to
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page.